# Removing a node from a double linked list?

Tags: java

Here's the method up to now

```
public DNode removeDnode(DNode v, DNode e, DNode f)
{
    e = v.nextNode();
    f = v.prevNode();
    f.setNext() = e;
    e.setPrev() = f;
    v.setPrev(null);
    v.setNext(null);
    size = size - 1;
    return v;
}
```

Here's my node class

```
public class DNode
{

public String element;
public DNode next;
public DNode previous;

public DNode(String e, DNode n)
{
    element = e;
    next = n;
}    

public void setElement(String newElem) 
{ 
    element = newElem; 
}
public void setNext(DNode newNext) 
{ 
    next = newNext; 
}
public void setPrev(DNode newPrev)
{
    previous = newPrev;
}
public String getElement() 
{ 
    return element; 
}
public DNode nextNode() 
{
  return next;
}
public DNode prevNode() 
{
  return previous;
}

}
```

I'm getting the error 'method setNext in class DNode cannot be applied to given types but I don't know why. Any help?

(Don't read this this is to use characters so it will let me post)

EDIT: new method below

```
public DNode removeDnode(DNode current)
{
    DNode next = current.nextNode();
    DNode previous = current.prevNode();
    previous.setNext(next);
    next.setPrev(previous);
    current.setPrev(null);
    current.setNext(null);
    size = size - 1;
    return current;
}
```

but how do I deal with the end and beginning of the list

Comment: `f.setNext() = e;` is not legal Java

Comment: @aix what? it's probably wrong but I'm just trying to get it to work. Yep it only works in the middle of a linked list and needs all three node inputting which I didn't want.

Comment: What I was getting at was that you could help us to help you by making your code a bit more understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
f.setNext(e);
e.setPrev(f);
```

Comment: Among many other things. To remove a node, you shouldn't have to pass in three nodes. By nature, a doubly-linked list node will have everything contained in the one object that you need to do a removal.